# XML string resources sharing between two projects for Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two android projects : Prj 1 and Prj 2. I am referring Prj2 in Prj1 via buildpath(add project feature) and using one of the UI custom class of Prj2 in Prj1. Class is using string xml resources for UI attributes in Prj 2. Now  I am able to access those attributes in Prj 1 only by adding string xml resources again in my Prj 1. I don't want to again manually copy xml resources of Prj 2 in Prj 1 again. Is there any way that Prj 1 will refer Prj 2 xml resources without adding them again?

Answer (score 0):

In general, this does work and does happened, the Strings are imported to the dependent project(**Prj1**)

Make sure you add the project(**Prj2**) as an android lib.

While referring to the **R** class, check out its **FQN**, and be sure you refer to the **Prj2**.

This is a common issue, that in a class you already referred to your project(**Prj1**) **R** file, and then trying to access your lib(**Prj2**) **R** file, and you can't figure out why you can't seem to find the fields...

It is because the first R file has already been imported to the class, so next time when you would refer to your lib R file, it must be with its **Fully Qualified Name**.